# Is logging an exception into a MessageBox a good practice?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I work on a team with a bunch of programmers who have a background in Java and Eclipse. Now in the project we work on in the C# code i see this code almost everywhere and most the times MUCH bigger:

```
try{
    var result = WebService.GetUser("John Cena");
    MyLabel.Text = result.Username;
}
catch(Exception e){
    MessageBox.Show(e);
}
```

above would fail if the webservice crashed(unless it's atomic), or if the result is null.

I would prefer the exception thrown in VS editor rather than a messagebox with no tracing. I'm advising everyone on the team to NEVER EVER use a try catch block. Mainly because they abuse them.

I would like to hear some professional advice on how exceptions should/shouldn't be handled.

Comment: Umm...sometimes you do in fact need to use a `try/catch`.  A blanket banning of the concept is unlikely to be generally beneficial.  As for your actual question, no, you probably shouldn't inflict exceptions and their stack traces onto your actual users.  (though logging it is a good idea)

Comment: We use a separate method to handle and even log the errors produce from `try/catch`. I 'm not agree with NOT using `try/catch` because it's essential in C# programming.

Comment: `try/catch` should be avoid for internal operations,but for `I/O` (database calls, etc.) they are very beneficial.

Comment: If you think you should NEVER EVER use a try/catch block you should change your user profile from saying "And my code is always awesome!".

Comment: I would mention when i said NEVER EVER use i didn't mean it. I still said it because these morons I'm programming with would have a function about 300 lines long and the first instruction is a try{ followed by approx 295 lines of "do everything".

Comment: @CyberFox, those programmers probably come from a Java background.  There, exceptions turn from a helpful concept for error reporting into a contractual obligation to always consider them in all circumstances.  Checked exceptions are one of those ideas that seem great in principle but are utterly horrible in practice.

Comment: Just me scratching the surface on Java, but i have stumbled upon this. Like when i made a method and the compiler threw bungies that i had declare what kind of errors the functions would throw or i should wrap the usage in an explicit throw. I found this a very... Interesting approach to problem solving. I'd love to have an extended discussion about this but SO ain't that kind of place. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, logging all exceptions in `MessabeBox` is bad practice. For example, you'll get `NullReferenceException` and show it to user. And what? Whant user should do? Does he know, what is `NullReferenceException`? What usefull information he will get? Zero.
You must log all exceptions in some storage, but show only "business" errors. For example: "You have no permission" and so on.
`NullReferenceException` is very low level exception to show it in message box.

Read more about [exception handling strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193772/what-should-be-the-best-exception-handling-strategy).

Comment: Good reasoning. Not useful for the end user. As i test our application it is endlessly annoying with these error boxes that keeps popping up. If anyone had to take over their project. God help them!

Answer (score 2):

Logging exceptions in message boxes are ugly and not user friendly.

For Back-end code we do like this;

```
try
{
     DoSomething();
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
     //Logs all details of the exception including full stack trace..
     ExceptionManager.LogError("Exception occured on 'DoSomething' method", ex);
}
```

For GUI;

```
try
{
    DoSomething();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Custom form to show all details of the exception
    (new formExceptionHandller(ex, ex.Message)).ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Log all exceptions
- Show only a standard error message to the user
- Also make sure that the logged message is notified to the relevant technical-group, which can either be automated (right after logging) or on user reporting (give an option to the user to "report to admin" kind of thing)

Comment: The system that works well for us is to log exception message, trace, Environment.MachineName, Environment.Username and Progam version to a database table that has auto-id primary key field, and report the id back to the user e.g. "There was a problem processing your request. The ref for this error is XXXX. If you keep seeing this message then please ring IT support team on XXXX quoting this number and details that might help us fix the issue." This table can get big over time, so it's worth having a SQL job that summarises and deletes entries over a month old to a table of unique entries.